# count the looping

Tags: php

Need help please.

What I need is when looping it will count how many loops after reaches zero.

```
$variable=50;//this is not fixed
$loop=0;
//------------------//
$variable-10;
//the $variable becomes 40
//$loop becomes 1
//repeat the process
$variable-10;
//the $variable becomes 30
//$loop becomes 2
//until the variable reaches zero then
//$loop becomes 5
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: I need a new car. Can you do that for me?

Comment: What have you tried is going to be my slogan from now on. Beautifully written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$variable = 50;
$loop = 0;
while($variable > 0)
{
    $variable -= 10;
    $loop++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

implement your variable $variable=50 inside loop

```
$count=0;
for ($variable=50; $variable<=0; $variable-=10){
$count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Golfing!

```
for($v=50,$c=0;($v-=10)>0;++$c);
echo $c;
```

At the end of this very short script, `$c` will represent the number of times the **code part** of the loop was executed. Inherently, it also represents the number of times the **incrementing sequence** was executed.

This is in contrast to the number of times the **test of the loop** was executed, which is inherently higher by 1, due to the last case before exeting.